# Android audio and voice processing

Tags: android

I am new to android and presently doing android voice recording application. I want top know which format is best for saving audio file in android. (i.e   RAW-AMR or 3gp or mp4).So rhat we can hear playback sound loudly in device.

Is there any alternative way to increase audio sound through voice processing in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this link involves every answer related to `Audio_Processing` whether it is *Pre-Processing* or *Post-Processing*: [Android_Audio_Processing_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC), You can also visit this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58546599/10413749

Answer (score 4):

**Question:** Which bear is best?  **Answer:** Black Bear

Seriously though, you would need to state your criteria for the audio file for us to make a codec recommendation.  Does it need to be portable?  Best compression?  Highest fidelity?

The codec that you choose has no affect on the *loudness* of audio that will be played over the device, so this should not factor into your criteria.

**Is there an alternative way to increase audio?**
Yes, if you are recording audio from the microphone then you can amplify the audio data before you save it to a file.

Let an audio sample from the microphone be represented by the function:

```
f(t)
```

**Amplification** is achieved by multiplying the audio sample by some factor A

```
A * f(t)
```

Comment: Can you please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339328/android-audiorecord-with-channel-in-stereo-read-raw-audio-buffer-resulted-in-mix

Comment: I think this link involves every answer related to `Audio_Processing` whether it is *Pre-Processing* or *Post-Processing*: [Android_Audio_Processing_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AGC(Automatic Gain Control) module from WebRTC to increase sound level.
I didn't find any simple Java API yet. You can use C++ API via JNI.
Have a look here, [WebRTC AGC (Automatic Gain Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706446/webrtc-agc-automatic-gain-control) .

Answer (score 0):

> I want top know which format is best for saving audio file in android.

To save voice audio on Android (or any other platform), take a look at [Opus](https://opus-codec.org/). It's a free, state-of-the-art audio codec that also supports voice mode.